# f77 file passing ifort compile but failed when using gfortran

Tags: fortran, gfortran

I am trying to compile a f77 file ([dfsynthe.for](http://wwwuser.oats.inaf.it/castelli/sources/dfsynthe/dfsynthe.for)) using gfortran.
Before that I tryed to compile it using ifort by `ifort -double-size 64 -save -o dfsynthe.exe dfsynthe.for`, and it worked.
However when I tried using gfortran by `gfortran -std=legacy -fdec -w -o dfsynthe.exe dfsynthe.for` I got a bunch or errors. I assume that there are some differences in the syntax when using gfortran and ifort, but I have no idea what exactly they are.

My ifort version is `ifort (IFORT) 19.0.3.199 20190206` and gfortran version is `GNU Fortran (Ubuntu 8.3.0-6ubuntu1~18.10.1) 8.3.0`.

The errors I got from gfortran are mainly in five types:

```
dfsynthe.for:135:51:

       OPEN(UNIT=15,STATUS='NEW',FORM='UNFORMATTED',
                                                   1
Error: Syntax error in OPEN statement at (1)
```

```
dfsynthe.for:434:20:

       CLOSE(UNIT=12,DISP='DELETE')
                    1
Error: Syntax error in CLOSE statement at (1)
```

```
dfsynthe.for:475:11:

      2 3046.604,2238.320,1713.711,1354.044,1096.776,
           1
Error: Syntax error in DATA statement at (1)
```

```
dfsynthe.for:3225:29:

   969 IF(T.GE.5000.)GO TO 979
                             1
Error: Label 979 referenced at (1) is never defined
```

```
dfsynthe.for:2327:48:

       EQUIVALENCE (D(21),D5(1)),(D(26),D6(1)),(D(31),D7(1))
                                                1
Error: Rank mismatch in array reference at (1) (1/2)
```

Here is the link for [dfsynthe.for](http://wwwuser.oats.inaf.it/castelli/sources/dfsynthe/dfsynthe.for) and the error log file [error.log](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1a94zGc53IG810wgME2GyySRUjON0onow/view?usp=sharing).

Comment: The code isn't (from what you've presented) valid Fortran code. Do you have reason to believe it should be compilable by gfortran? If not, you're going to have to edit the source to make it understandable by your compiler, but in this case to get advice it would be much better to make a complete example we can look at (see [mre]).

Comment: they statements the OP listed are all old fortran lines and all are properly written.

Comment: @jmh, `CLOSE(UNIT=12,DISP='DELETE')` at the very least is not Fortran.

Comment: I don't recognize the DISP='DISPLAY' option but that could just be me.  Other lines seem fine.  Fortran has changed a lot but the lines written look like old punch cards fortran 66.

Comment: we know its Fortran because it ran using a different compiler!

Comment: yes I think `DISP` is an alternative for `STATUS`, and after changing all the `DISP` to `STATUS` the error in `CLOSE` vanished.

Comment: good catch.  keep me posted please.

Answer (score 0):

You may have the lines offset by 1 space or more. It appears you are trying to run old Fortran legacy code. Nothing wrong with that and it should run using Gfortran. Check your source code and confirm all statements start in column seven. If a line has a line number, as in `1000 continue` be sure line number is in columns 2-6. If this still doesn't work or source code is formatted properly leave a note in the comments telling what you learned.
You might try renaming the file to dfsynthe.F77 and seeing how that works.

Comment: Did you look at the source?  It will not compile with gfortran without some effort to remove the non-standard code.

Comment: i didn't see any non-standard code. the code is old fortran 66 i think.

Comment: Close(unit=12)  is standard fortran.  i just don't recognize DISP='DELETE'..

Comment: we know it is indeed valid fortran cause it compiled and ran with a different compiler!

Comment: Try line 135 and following `OPEN(UNIT=15,TYPE='NEW',FORM='UNFORMATTED',RECORDTYPE='FIXED',BLOCKSIZE=32000,RECL=8)`   What is `TYPE`?  What is `RECORDTYPE`?  What is `BLOCKSIZE`?

Comment: Looks like the code was originally written to read from a tape. The very old tape like on reel-to-reel systems if you've ever seen them. They were common in physics labs as late as the late 1990's to record large amounts of data.  Large is a relative term.

Comment: i'd have to look thru a fortran 66 manual to find out what they mean but those terms were common back then.

Comment: @evets The description of `TYPE` can be found [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/805-4939/6j4m0vnaf/index.html), it is an alternative to `STATUS`.

Comment: `RECORDTYPE` and `BLOCKSIZE` present in [ifort's page1](https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/documentation/fortran-compiler-developer-guide-and-reference/top/language-reference/file-operation-i-o-statements/open-statement-specifiers/open-recordtype-specifier.html) and [ifort's page2](https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/documentation/fortran-compiler-developer-guide-and-reference/top/language-reference/file-operation-i-o-statements/open-statement-specifiers/open-blocksize-specifier.html), but seems gfortran doesn't recognize them.

Comment: Removing `RECORDTYPE` and `BLOCKSIZE` works for compiling through gfortran, but I am not sure if the behaviour of reading/writing will be different or not. Sorry for spliting the comments because the links are too long...

Comment: @MKK, as I stated above "It will not compile with gfortran without some effort to remove non-standard code."  You cannot just change `TYPE` to `STATUS` in the `OPEN` statements.  You need to add a `FILE='something here'`, or you need to change `TYPE='NEW'` to `STATUS='SCRATCH'`.  But, it seems `SCRATCH` conflicts with `RECORDTYPE`.  Do you now change `RECORTYPE='FIXED'` to `ACCESS='DIRECT'`?

Answer (score 0):

You have some tabs in the source file. Replace them with spaces and you will get a little farther.

Comment: See the comment by evets under the answer by jmh. The code is not standard Fortran at all. Gfortran is able to cope with tabs if properly setup.